# How can I use authentication without Bootstrap?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-authentication

In Laravel, I know running `composer require laravel/ui` and then `php artisan ui vue --auth` creates authentication scaffolding but it uses Bootstrap. Is there a way to create this scaffolding without Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately and as I know, there is no alternative for the bootstrap UI in laravel authentication scaffolding, as I know there is a tailwind but the last update on the repo was 2 years ago so not sure if it is supported now

https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss

also, you can change it or create a new one, all view files in this path

```
resources/views/auth
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want use TailWindCss And Compatibility with Laravel V9
You Can Use this package :
[Github Repo](https://github.com/xndbogdan/laravel-tailwindcss-preset)

It's very simple and I've been using it for a few minutes